# Enabling ProGuard for a single module in a 2 module project

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

Assuming I have an Android **library** project (named **X**) which I use to create an **AAR** file for later use, can I have this structure below?

```
    Project X
        Module A
            proguard disabled
            consumes classes from module B
        Module B
            proguard enabled
            consumes native Java/Android SDK classes
```

When I build **Project X**, I want to create an AAR file which will publicly expose classes from **Module A**.

*Note: Enabling ProGuard in **Module A** too and excluding everything with a proguard rule is not an option in my case.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of current Android Studio 3.4, it does not support your project structure if the said `Project X` and `Module A` as well as `Module B` are all Android **Library** projects.  Instead of your project structure, you can try below structure:

```
Module A
    proguard disabled
    dependsOn B
    consumes classes from module B
Module B
    proguard enabled
    consumes native Java/Android SDK classes
Project X
    proguard disabled
    dependsOn A and B
```